# Local ethereum node returns different than Javascript vm

Tags: solidity, dapps

```
contract Marketplace {   
    uint256 transferBudget = 1 ether;
    bytes32[] ids;
    enum Position{
        Goalkeeper, Defender, Midfielder, Attacker, Coach
    }

    struct Footballer{
        bytes32 id;
        string name;
        address owner;
        Position position;
        uint price;
    }
    Footballer[] footballers;

    //function buy(uint ID, uint quantity) public payable {}

    function deposit() public payable {
        if(msg.value>0){
            transferBudget = transferBudget+msg.value;
        }
    }

    function getTransferBudget() public view returns(uint256){
        return transferBudget;
    }

    function update(bytes32 ID, uint newPrice) public {
        for(uint i=0; i<footballers.length; i++){
            if(footballers[i].id==ID && msg.sender==footballers[i].owner){
                footballers[i].price = newPrice;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

     function newProduct2() public pure returns(uint) {
        return 12;
    }

    //creates a new product and returns its ID
    function newProduct(string name, uint price, Position position) public returns(bytes32 id) {
        bytes32 hashId = keccak256(name,price,position);
        Footballer memory footballer = Footballer(hashId, name, msg.sender,position,price);
        footballers.push(footballer);
        ids.push(hashId);
        return hashId;
    }

    function getProducts() public view returns(bytes32[]) {
       return ids;
    }

    function getPrice(bytes32 ID) public view returns (uint) {
        for(uint i=0; i<footballers.length; i++){
            if(footballers[i].id==ID){
                return footballers[i].price;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So here is the problem... the functions which are not views do not return any value when I run my local ethereum node but it works as expected in Javascript VM.

Comment: In general, transactions do not have return values. Remix + JavaScript VM is the one doing something strange here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sendTransaction` in JS EVM in Remix will be executed synchronously, so you'll be able to get the return value when sending a transaction. With a node this will not work since the call is processed asynchronously and there is no way to store a return value in the transaction receipt. There is only a status field which can be 0 or 1.

A pattern to communicate the result to the caller is to emit events. These can be fetched from the transaction receipt.

```
event FootballerCreated(bytes32 hashId);

function newProduct(string name, uint price, Position position) public {
    ...
    emit FootballerCreated (hashId);
}
```